# Electrolysis in water with baking soda

Tags: water, electrolysis

Many demonstrations of electrolysis show the use of baking soda and a 9 volt battery for electrolysis of water. As a science experiment, I tested different voltages by adding more batteries. In my experiment, I used distilled water. After letting the electrolysis happen for 5 minutes, the 18 volt test had yellow discoloration in the water. Because I couldn't find any places online that mention this or explain what it is, I thought to ask. Perhaps it is not a common thing?

[Edit] Answer: Most likely cause was degradation of poor electrode material with too much electricity.

Comment: Electrode material is more important than you seem to assume.

Comment: Note A: The electrodes (the exposed bits) I am using are stainless steel alligator clips. 
Note B: Kosher salt is NOT a suitable medium, it uses yellow prussiate of soda as an anti caking agent. YPoS (Ferrocyanide) is stable until mixed with _Hydrogen_ and _Ample electricity_, after which it turns into hydrogen cyanide.

Comment: Stainless or not, pretty much _any_ metal anode will dissolve.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't considered the electrodes as an input for contamination. Less worried now.

Comment: 18 volts are also pure overkill. Above 3 - 4 V or so, you just produce more heat with higher voltage.